# Reading in hex value gives the wrong number in C++

Tags: c++, hex

I am trying to read in a hex value using the following code. It is supposed to read in a value from dataFile and the value is supposed to be "810c0001".

```
int in;
dataFile>>hex>>in>>dec;
cout <<"I just wrote the value: "<<hex<<in<<dec<<endl;
```

After I run the program the output is shown as "I just wrote the value: 7fffffff".
I noticed this problem only occurs when the most significant bit is filled. If I change the inputs '8'to a '7'  I get the correct output of: "I just wrote the value: 710c0001" What are some things I can do to read in the correct value?
Thank you

Comment: Hex 810c0001 is an awfully big number... You are overflowing your destination type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `int` size is 4bytes which means it can only store values from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

7fffffff=2,147,483,647

The value 0x810c0001 is out of range. You can change the variable type to `unsigned int` to be able to store larger values in a case that you only care about positive numbers.

Comment: Thank you, I just switched it to an unsigned int.

Comment: Specifically, you should use the most appropriate type for your input. If all your values are positive numbers with this range, then a `uint32_t` (or `unsigned int` on some systems) is right. But don't just randomly change types to randomly get greater range.

Comment: Okay Thank you, I just need to know the bit value in each spot so having a negative number is not necessary.